# UITableView between UIAlertController header and controls

Tags: ios, objective-c

I wanted to have a UITableView between the UIAlertController header and the controls(buttons).

Is it possible to seperate the buttons from the controller and move them below the UITableView?

Basically I want to add an UIView just like an textfield I can add via `addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler`

My current code (reduced):

AlertTableViewController.h:

```
@protocol AlertTableDelegate <NSObject>
@end
@interface AlertTableViewController : UIAlertController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>{
}

@property(nonatomic,weak) id <AlertTableDelegate>alertDelegate;
@property(nonatomic,strong) UITableView* myTableView;
@property(nonatomic,strong) UIAlertController* myController;

-(id)initWithData:(NSArray*)data title:(NSString*)title;
```

AlertTableViewController.m:

```
@implementation AlertTableViewController
-(id)initWithData:(NSArray *)data title:(NSString *)title{

    if( (self = [super init] ) != nil ){

        _myController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:title
                                                            message:@"text!"
                                                     preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
        UIAlertAction* dismissAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Abbrechen" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {       
        }];

        UIAlertAction* downloadAction = [ UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Download" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
        }];

        [_myController addAction:dismissAction];
        [_myController addAction:downloadAction];

        self.data = [data mutableCopy];
[self prepare];
}

- (void)prepare{
    _myTableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 100, 200,200) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    _myTableView.dataSource  = self;
    _myTableView.delegate = self;
    [_myController.view addSubview:_myTableView];
    [_myController.view sizeToFit];
}
```

The results are dissatisfying because both components are ignoring each other at the moment:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it's not possible.

`UIAlertController` is a very convenient view if you want to show something simple and query the user. If you want to put a table inside, you have to create your own control.

Just create a class like `XXMyCustomAlert` that will behave just like `UIAlertController` - creates a black overlay with opacity, a header and buttons - and put your desired control inside.

Here's an example:

https://github.com/wimagguc/ios-custom-alertview